# Piwik 1.5.1 Wrong number of visits and (unique) visitors

Tags: matomo, visitors

i just updated my piwik from 1.1.1 to 1.5.1 and having problems with the numbers of vists and visitors.

Each time i send a tracking request (with firefox 5) piwik increases the number of pages, vistis and visitors. That will be ok for my first request, but all of my following requests should only increase the number of pages, not visits or visitors.

Same request in IE9 increases the pages and visits. The number of visitors looks fine and increases only for the first request.
The old version did'nt have this behaviour.

I'm using the async tracking and this is what's defined in my pages:

```
var piwikSiteId = '2';
var _paq = _paq || [];
(function(){
var u="https://piwik.mydomain.net/piwik/";
_paq.push(['setSiteId', '2']);
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
var d=document,
g=d.createElement('script'),
s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.type='text/javascript';
g.defer=true;
g.async=true;
g.src=u+'piwik.js';
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})();
```

I also tried the standard integration which was generated by piwik - the behaviour is the same as described above.

Piwik is installed under a subdomain like piwik.mydomain.net and the site is available under website.mydomain.net. It looks like a cookie problem for me but i'm not sure.

Maybe someone can help - where do i have to look solving this issue?

Thanks,
JJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in piwik and is now resolved.
[Piwik changeset 5086](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/changeset/5086)